# Simple prediction example

Tags: machine-learning

Given Training data:

> x y output
>   0 0 0
>   1 0 1
>   1 1 1

Predict output for Testing data:

> x y output
>   0 1  ?

The particular input variable combination was not seen before. So, would you predict 0 (cos it's 'closer' to 00), or 1 (cos it's closer to 11), or a probability value between 0 & 1 ?

Answer (score 2):

Answering that essentially boils down to finding the true joint distribution $f_{X,Y,O}$ of the process that generates those samples.

Assuming that the joint distribution of the learning and testing sets are identical (which is a common assumption in supervised classification), your answer is by finding this:

\begin{equation}
\text{predicted output} = \underset{output \in \{0,1\}}{\text{arg max}} f_{X,Y,O}(0,1,output)
\end{equation}

But the problem is that you don't have the true probability density function $f_{X,Y,O}$, and you *cannot* even find it because your input is limited.

Therefore, you need to *guess* $f_{X,Y,O}$. Usually such guess is referred to by $\hat f_{X,Y,O}$ (note that hat).

If you take the problem statement literally, usually there is an uncountably infinite number of such guessed PDFs $\hat f_{X,Y,O}$, and all of them are technically correct.

Here is why you need to use your domain knowledge to cancel out out many of the technically-relavant that you know (based on your domain knowledge) that are not going to lead to correct classification.

No learning algorithm can fix this problem. Learning algorithms that are better than others (for cases such as your example) are only so because of simply assuming extra things beyond what the question states, which does not necessarily means that they are better algorithms as much as it means that these are algorithms that were lucky to assume something that seemed to work in your specific problem.

You may Google for *kernel density estimation*.

Comment: i know some of these words :) 
i'm not a math major and i'm not trying to find a mathematical function per se (like linear regression etc.) to fit the data best. I'm trying to predict the output for machine learning competitions where there are a large number of input variables and training data, and there are only 2 possible scenarios - either the exact input was seen before (then predict the same training output), or it wasn't (which basically boils down to my above question with 2 variables, and can be extended to any number of variables)

Comment: @sqld-_-ba OK, for that sort of stuff, you can try different software that implements classification algorithms (e.g. KNN, RF, SVM, etc -- all of them will predict the unseen data), and see which one is more accurate. If you are OK with Python you can go this website http://scikit-learn.org/ download their software and use it to predict the unseen (this software has implementations of many algorithms that predict the unseen, including KNN, RF, SVM, etc -- so you have a lot of room to try and test).

Answer (score 1):

Your dataset is tiny and multiple, very different, "rules" can be defined for it, e.g.

- `output = 0 + 1*x + 0*y`,
- `output = max(x,y)`,
- `output = x`,
- `output = x or y`,
- `output = draw randomly 0 or 1` etc.

...all of those rules are perfectly valid and yield error-free results on your training set. The problem is that you haven't seen the $(0,1)$ combination in the training set, so not much can be said about it. There is nothing in your data that suggests that $(0,1)$ is "closer" neither to $(1,1)$, nor to $(0,0)$.

With such limited data and no background knowledge probably the best that you can get is non-machine learning guesstimates like: (a) "predicting" the most frequent class: $1$, (b) randomly assigning $0$, or $1$, (c) randomly assigning $1$ with probability $2/3$, or $0$ with probability $1/3$ (proportions in your observed sample).

No matter what method you'll choose, your final estimate would be more related to *assumptions* that you made about the data since it does not permit you to make any reliable conclusions. The more complicated method for prediction you will choose, the more assumptions you would need to make about your data.

Answer (score 0):

A linear model will ascribe the weights to x and y and use them accordingly to calculate the prediction. 
It doesn't have to have seen all possible permutations of x and y to calculate the weights.

Comment: Yes, it will calculate *something*, the obvious choice is `0 + 1*x + 0*y`, however the pattern could be possibly `output = x and y`, then the prediction would be obviously wrong. Why do you consider linear model to be appropriate in here?

Comment: Well, you have to start somewhere. From the discussion above the OP is not seeking academic depth. So a linear model is a good start to explain how this is usually dealt with.